# Integration of exponential of a complex number

Tags: integration

When we integrate $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{(a+bi)x}dx$$ I understand that $a<0$ in order to have an answer, but am I right to say that b has no such restriction? 
As $e^{bix}=cos(bx)+isin(bx)$, so regardless of whether b is positive or negative, the function is still integrable.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The negative real part $a$ provides the exponential decay that guarantees integrability.

Comment: One way to think of this is that the function $ \ e^a \cdot cis(bx) \ $ has an "envelope" defined by $ \ e^a \ $ and $ \ -(e^a) \ $ .  Since, for $ \ a < 0 \ $ , the area bounded by this envelope over the interval of integration is finite, the areas described by the sine and cosine "components" will certainly be finite as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate by definition of an indefinite integral that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{(a + bi)x} \; dx
&= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left[ \frac{e^{(a + bi)x}}{a + bi} \right]_0^k \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{e^{(a + bi)k} - e^{(a + bi)0}}{a + bi}
\end{align*}

If $a < 0$, $\left|e^{(a + bi)k}\right| = |e^{ak}| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, so $e^{(a+bi)k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, hence the limit (and the original integral) exist.  So you're right that any $b$ works.

Comment: You must have posted this as I was writing my almost-identical answer.  Let me vote you up in the spirit of sportsmanship! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.  Let's integrate up to some fixed real value $R>0$, assuming that $a$ and $b$ are not both zero:
$$
 \int_0^R dx\, e^{(a+ib)x} = \frac{1}{a+ib} \left[ e^{(a+ib)x} \right]^R_0
= \frac{1}{a+ib} \left[ e^{(a+ib)R} - 1 \right]
$$
Now, $|e^{(a+ib)R}| = |e^{aR}|$, so if $a>0$, the integral diverges as $R \to \infty$.  If $a<0$, on the other hand, $e^{aR} \to 0$, so it converges to
$$
-\frac{1}{a+ib} ~.
$$
The value of $b$ did not come into this reasoning.

(Note: The marginal value $a=0$ is interesting, but the integral doesn't converge in the naive sense.)